# UItableView doesn't show my text

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I am adding some text in `UItableview` but it doesn't appear in my `UITableView` when I test it. Can someone help me with that?

In `UITableview` there is a button called `Basic` from where I'm adding some text and I want to connect it to another view controller. But when I run it, it doesn't show the text.

Should I write some code for that?
I tried this also but it didnt work :

```
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: i mean i wanna Add some text in UITableView and it doesn't show when i run it..

Comment: this code is not enough add code related with `UITableView `

Comment: i know that, thats why i ask someone to help :)n

Comment: can your share your sample project?

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5QBdeznBKkzfndKcG5MMkRadFdSQXp5eEdxVW0ycGNjaDdZNUlKTlVBSFN1VDAtS3JDMjA] here is i share the project

Comment: [ https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5QBdeznBKkzfndKcG5MMkRadFdSQXp5eEdxVW0ycGNjaDdZNUlKTlVBSFN1VDAtS3JDMjA ]

Comment: Here the link to see the picture, this one is more Clear :)

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5QBdeznBKkzflo5SXJmUlNGS1dPNUF3UkMwX2xKVUFSVjE2SWNWUFpneGR4WmtJX2Z5aXM&usp=sharing]

Comment: Is this what you need: https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Simple-table ?

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh, yes. but you know there is one problem, how can i add navigation controller for them?